# How to create a date field used specific dates fetched from a database in Symfony2?

Tags: php, date, symfony

I stored some dates in my database. The date format is `2014-02-22 00:21:23`. Now, I'm trying to create a `date field` used that data. So, a user can choose only the available dates fetched from the database, the other dates should be colored as gray to represent the unavailability.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('date', 'date', array(
                'input' => 'string',
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

I don't find any examples to achieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The best practice would probably be to create your own custom field, I've yet to use them to their full extent but it seems to be a good place for this. Alternatively you could just use a select field with a query to get only available dates, depending on what your exact project constraints are.

Comment: Have you tired jQuerUI or http://lab.xero.nu/bootstrap_calendar/, could help you with the calendar side of things.